# Android Test Orchestrator: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: -26

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-test-orchestrator

When launching androidConnectTests I receive an error:

```
caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: -26 Package androidx.test.services new target SDK 14 doesn't support runtime permissions and old target does
```

This started happening after enabling the Android Test Orchestrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to uninstall any old version of `androidx.test.services`

```sh
adb uninstall androidx.test.services
```

Then you need to make sure you are using the [latest version of androidx-test](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/test).

See these instructions for setting up the latest version of Android Test Orchestrator.
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator